# is there a way to force iCloud sync?

Tags: icloud

On my mac, i deleted a bunch of songs and checked "delete from iCloud" checkbox. On my iPhone (10 minutes later), songs are still there.

Is there a way to force the sync between devices on demand? (and ultimately delete them from iPhone)

Comment: I've tried updating my icloud.com e-mail account in Mail app on my iPhone and it helped.

Comment: How exactly did you "update" your account? Log out and in again?

Comment: No. Just checked for new mail.

Comment: On my mac it helped to press 'alt'&'cmd' - hoover the finder symbol and choose "restart finder"... then it started a new synch process...

Comment: So much has changed with iCloud, I'm closing this. If this can have a specific OS certiorari and explanation on if this is about iTunes music or files in iCloud documents, we can certainly reopen it as less broad/more clear.