# Force iCloud Drive to sync under Yosemite

Tags: icloud, macos

There are many questions of forcing iCloud to sync, but they are generally  [old and unclear as to the details](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48718/is-there-a-way-to-force-icloud-sync).

I changed the file structure at my Mac, but the iOS App (Pages) doesn't seem to take the new update.

When I look through the folder structure via another iOS App, there is still the old structure. So it seems that my changes on the Mac didn't update yet.

Is there a way in Yosemite to force the iCloud sync?

> There has to be a service which is triggered and runs in the background. Which service is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. The sync process is kicked off when you disconnect from all networks and then reconnect. You can debug things using `brctl log -w` on the Mac and AppleCare can also help you with iOS cloud sync diag logs if you have an issue that needs that level of debugging.

The `brctl` man page has information on diagnostic files and you can also use `sysdiagnose` to assist with cloud sync diagnosis.

The actual sync daemon is `bird` but you don't run it directly.

Lastly, before digging into the logs, I often use https://iCloud.com to verify that the Mac and iOS devices are either in sync with the cloud version so I know which of the three is lagging.

Comment: "I often use https://iCloud.com to verify that the Mac and iOS devices are either in sync with the cloud version so I know which of the three is lagging." 

Just how do you do that?

Comment: @Calion Say if you made a note on iphone, if it appears on icloud, mac is at fault. If it doesn't, iphone is at fault.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a VPN, that may also occasionally stall things. Try just stopping and restarting the VPN.